# Facebook app returns not showing

Tags: facebook

my app now it does not show my website on the app.

This is the app, https://apps.facebook.com/compuservboricua/

i migrate the application page to only show only the application and now it returns a blank page instead of the site.

And the page tab not even showing. https://www.facebook.com/CompuServBoricua?sk=app_142900852405888

i tried to fix it but only show a blank page. How can I fix this?

Note: it was working fine 2 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that the https url is not set for your app in the app settings, or the https version of your site is not working.  Maybe the ssl cert is bad on your site.  https://compuservboricua.forumstech.com vs http://compuservboricua.forumstech.com

Comment: thanks for the reply,  well my site does not have the secure connection, like i said on the note it was working fine 2 days ago with the current site http://compuservboricua.forumstech.com/ in the canvas url... when i migrate the application page to only the applicacion it change something and now shows only a blank page...

Comment: the weird thing is the application shows the correct title that i have on my site witch is .::CompuServ Boricua::. - Computer System Entertainment - Portal,  but it does not show the site...

Comment: Facebook now requires both an http and an https version of the app to run.  The non-secure one pulls up fine for me.  The https version is not loading.

Comment: mine was working fine without the secure connection, i don't know what change, what can i put in secure URL principal page application? , when i enter this url there https://apps.facebook.com/compuservboricua/ it show app problem please try again later.

Comment: try the raw URL of your iframed app in both http and https, you will see the https version NOT load.  This is an issue with your Web Server or network settings no longer allowing ssl/443.

Comment: the one you entered into the app settings section for http and https